# Processor hanging and causing computer crash whilst playing games

Tags: windows-7, cpu, minidumps

Recently I upgraded my HDD to a 1TB and reformatted my computer (due to it suddenly taking several hours just to boot.)

After that whenever I play games my computer would freeze up, become unresponsive to all keyboard commands, keyboard locks (Num lock, capslock etc) would be unable to change and mouse would become unresponsive. After a few seconds to a minute the display picture would become deformed, sometimes a few seconds after that it would go to BSOD. A hard reboot is required and after that the computer boots fine and works exactly the same.
Sound either loops around 30 seconds of sound repeatedly, play a single 'note' infinitely (like a beep) or stop entirely.

The more intensive the game the more regularly crashes occurred and running Firefox in the background also seemed to increase the frequency of crashes.

I have tried to decrease the amount of CPU usage which decreases the frequency of the crashes however does not stop them entirely.
I have also monitored temperature of the APU which slowly climbs and reaches around 75 degrees just before crashing.

OS: Windows 7 64-bit
CPU: AMD A6-3670 APU with Radeon HD graphics
HDD: SAMSUNG HD103SJ ATA
RAM: 1 Crucial 4GB, Ballistix Smart Tracer 240-pin DIMM (with LEDs), DDR3 PC3-14900
Motherboard: Asrock A75M-HVS

> BugCheck 101, {31, 0, fffff88002f63180, 2}
>
> Probably caused by : Unknown_Image ( ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE )
>
> ### Followup: MachineOwner
>
> 0: kd> !analyze -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (101)
>   An expected clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor in an
>   MP system within the allocated interval. This indicates that the specified
>   processor is hung and not processing interrupts.
>   Arguments:
>   Arg1: 0000000000000031, Clock interrupt time out interval in nominal clock ticks.
>   Arg2: 0000000000000000, 0.
>   Arg3: fffff88002f63180, The PRCB address of the hung processor.
>   Arg4: 0000000000000002, 0.
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_4_PROC
>
> CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  System
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  d
>
> STACK_TEXT:
>   fffff880`03316528 fffff800`03130a4a : 00000000`00000101 00000000`00000031 00000000`00000000 fffff880`02f63180 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
>
> fffff880`03316530 fffff800`030e36f7 : fffff880`00000000 fffff800`00000002 00000000`00002711 00000000`00000001 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x4e3e
>
> fffff880`033165c0 fffff800`03025895 : fffff800`0304b460 fffff880`03316770 fffff800`0304b460 fffff800`00000000 : nt!KeUpdateSystemTime+0x377
>
> fffff880`033166c0 fffff800`030d6113 : 00000000`7f83af53 fffff800`03254e80 00000580`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpHpetClockInterrupt+0x8d
>
> fffff880`033166f0 fffff800`030de9f0 : fffff800`03254e80 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffff800`03250c48 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLock+0x163
>
> fffff880`03316880 fffff800`030c39d4 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 fffff880`03316ba0 00000000`00005da0 : nt!KeFlushMultipleRangeTb+0x260
>
> fffff880`03316950 fffff800`0315af25 : fffff800`03314b00 fffff800`00000001 00000000`00000001 fffff880`03316bb0 : nt!MiAgeWorkingSet+0x64a
>
> fffff880`03316b00 fffff800`030c3b06 : 00000000`00006c82 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`00000000 00000000`00000003 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x4c7f6
>
> fffff880`03316b80 fffff800`030c3fb3 : 00000000`00000008 fffff880`03316c10 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`00000000 : nt!MmWorkingSetManager+0x6e
>
> fffff880`03316bd0 fffff800`033762ea : fffffa80`039c0040 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`0399a040 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBalanceSetManager+0x1c3
>
> fffff880`03316d40 fffff800`030ca8e6 : fffff880`02f63180 fffffa80`039c0040 fffff880`02f6dfc0 bfd0ec17`c4c7b1e1 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
>
> fffff880`03316d80 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  kb
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: Unknown_Module
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  Unknown_Image
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_4_PROC_ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE
>
> BUCKET_ID:  X64_CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_4_PROC_ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: Have you checked the cooling apparatus in the system to ensure it's not clogged with dirt, or dislodged from its regular position?  Perhaps you bumped something while installing the new drive?

Comment: The fan was clogged with a lot of dust, after cleaning it out the temperature whilst gaming dropped to 40'C and crashes no longer occur so thanks.

Comment: No problem, I'll stick it in as an actual answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the cooling apparatus (fans, heat sinks, heat pipes, etc.) in the system to ensure it's not clogged with dirt, dust an debris.

Also ensure it isn't dislodged from its regular position (in case something got bumped while installing the new drive), because if it's not seated properly it won't cool properly.